# To which stream does xsel print the no newline warning?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, stderr, xsel

xsel is a program with which you can access system clipboard from command line. If there is no newline at the end of copied content, it prints a warning after the clipboard content like this:

```
$ xsel -b
copied text
\ No newline at end of selection
```

Earlier I used to think that this warning is printed to the standard error, but today I found that the warning is not there even if the standard error is merged with the standard output.`xsel-b |& less` just prints the copied text, without the warning. Why does it behave like this?

Comment: This is weird. Firstly, I do not have this error message. Secondly, such a message is surprising since the vast majority of the selections do not contain a newline. What is your version of `xsel` and what is your environment?

Comment: `xsel` has different behaviors depending on whether standard input or output are terminals. I suspect it only displays the error message when it's outputing to a terminal, not a pipe or file.

Comment: https://github.com/kfish/xsel/blob/master/xsel.c#L2259

Comment: https://github.com/kfish/xsel/commit/583f1a441c93686b99e82d8be621f5f06b669e31

Comment: I'm on arch linux and the upstream url for xsel is http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's weird it does write the warning to stderr but it's not there when stderr is redirected!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that that's the behaviour of `xsel` in not yet released versions of `xsel`. Introduced by [this change](https://github.com/kfish/xsel/commit/583f1a441c93686b99e82d8be621f5f06b669e31) in 2008.

It's common for X selections to contain text that doesn't end in newline characters. If you dump it as is, that results in an unterminated line being displayed. With old shells like `bash` the display becomes:

```
bash-4.4$ xsel -b
xselbash-4.4$
```

(here with the CLIPBOARD selection containing `xsel`). The next prompt ends up being appended to the content of the selection.

Modern shells like `zsh` or `fish` work around that be detecting when the output of the last command doesn't end in newline and give you a visual indication then.

With `zsh`:

```
prompt% xsel -p
xsel%
prompt%
```

(the reverse-video `%` after `xsel` being the indication that a newline was missing).

With `fish`:

```
prompt ~> xsel -p
x⏎
prompt ~>
```

Those newer `xsel` give you that visual indication themselves:

```
bash-4.4$ xsel -b
xsel
\ No newline at end of selection
bash-4.4$
```

Now, that is only useful if xsel is run at the prompt of an old interactive shell.

In particular, that "No newline" indication would not be desirable when used as:

```
selection=$(xsel -b)
```

(where `xsel`'s stdout is a pipe) or:

```
xsel -b > selection.txt
```

(where `xsel`'s stdout is a regular file).

That's why `xsel` only outputs that indication only when stdout goes to a tty device.

Now, where does it display it? Well, the intention is to display it on that tty device. If you run it under strace, you'll see:

```
$ strace -e write ./xsel -b
write(1, "xsel", 4xsel)                     = 4
write(2, "\n\\ No newline at end of selectio"..., 34
\ No newline at end of selection
) = 34
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Which confirms [the source](https://github.com/kfish/xsel/blob/master/xsel.c#L2259): it's output on stderr. And when stdout is not a terminal:

```
$ strace -e write ./xsel -b  > /dev/null
write(1, "$ strace -e write ./xsel -b | ca"..., 104) = 104
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

It's not output at all. Now one might argue it's a bit silly to output on stderr when the intent is to output that notification to the terminal (stderr could be redirected to a log file for instance as in `xsel -b 2> logfile`), but:

- Generally, when stdout is a terminal device, stderr is as well.
- That means you can disable that notification when run in a terminal with `xsel -b 2> /dev/null` which would be more efficient than `xsel -b | cat`.
- The `isatty()` would return true for a serial device that is not connected to a terminal.

Comment: That software is insane.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple enough to test with:

```
xsel -b > xsel.out 2> xsel.err
```

The message will be in one of the two files.  If it's in `xsel.out`, then the message is through standard output; if it is in the other file, then it is through standard error; if it is in neigher, then something very strange is happening, and you need to have a long, serious talk with your kernel.

Comment: It's perfectly possible for a process to write to the tty without regard for stdout or stderr: `( echo "on tty" >$(tty); echo "on stdout" >&1; echo "on stderr" >&2 ) 1>out 2>err`

Comment: As it happens, `xsel` no longer outputs that text when stdout does not go to a terminal device. `xsel -b 2> xsel.err` while stdout is a terminal would store that text in xsel.err though.

Comment: @DopeGhoti the clipboard content goes to xsel.out and xsel.err is empty.

Comment: @DopeGhoti can you help me out, the kernel is intimidating me. How should I start the conversation?